# Does anyone know what is this "Phrase Predict" in Access 2007?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

Does anyone know what is this "Phrase Predict" in Access 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Phrase predict is a Autocomplete feature in access which allows users to type in something without the user actually typing it.
- It involves predicting a word or phrase that the user wants to type and the program automatically types in for the user to save time. It predict the word being typed based on those already typed words.
- To speak the truth this feature gets annoying later.